# How to filter for time in a IsoDate field?

Tags: mongodb

In all documents of a `Order` collection, I have this field

```
"delivery_slot_date" : ISODate("2021-03-19T08:00:00.000+0000"),
```

We're filtering by date range only, but now we need to be able to filter by time range [without dates]. How can I take all orders when the TIME of `delivery_slot_date` is >= / <= a given time?

I'm using MongoDB 4.0.x

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#date-expression-operators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work

```
delivery_slot_date: {
  '$gte': ISODate("2019-11-21T00:00:40"),
  '$lt': ISODate("2019-11-21T23:59:59")
}
```

Here `gte` is 'greater than' and `lte` is 'lesser than'.
You can switch to `gt` and `lt` respectively if you want.

Comment: Dear Omkar, that's really great you are trying to help and it would be even better if you pay attention to the question you are answering. The OP is struggling to compare times, not dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         time: {
            $dateFromParts: {
               year: 1970, month: 1, day: 1,
               hour: { $hour: "$delivery_slot_date" },
               minute: { $minute: "$delivery_slot_date" },
               second: { $second: "$delivery_slot_date" },
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $match: {
         time: {
            $gte: ISODate("1970-01-01T09:00:00Z"),
            $lt: ISODate("1970-01-01T12:30:00Z")
         }
      }
   }
])
```

Depending on your interval you can also use this one, but it is lees flexible:

```
// Between 10:00:00 and 11:59:59
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $set: { parts: { $dateToParts: { date: "$delivery_slot_date" } } } },
   { $match: { "parts.hour": { $gte: 10, $lt: 12 } } },

])

// Between 10:10:00 and  10:29:59
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $set: { parts: { $dateToParts: { date: "$delivery_slot_date" } } } },
   { $match: { "parts.hour": 10, "parts.minute": { $gte: 10, $lt: 30 } } }
])
```